# What is console.log?

Tags: javascript, firebug, console.log

What is the use of `console.log`?

Please explain how to use it in JavaScript, with a code example.

Answer (score 466, accepted):

It's not a jQuery feature but a feature for debugging purposes. You can for instance log something to the console when something happens. For instance:

```
$('#someButton').click(function() {
  console.log('#someButton was clicked');
  // do something
});
```

You'd then see `#someButton was clicked` in Firebug’s “Console” tab (or another tool’s console — e.g. Chrome’s Web Inspector) when you would click the button.

For some reasons, the console object could be unavailable. Then you could check if it is - this is useful as you don't have to remove your debugging code when you deploy to production:

```
if (window.console && window.console.log) {
  // console is available
}
```

Comment: Google Chrome's Developer tools also has a console integrated.

Comment: "This is useful as you don't have to remove your debugging code when you deploy to production" <-- What if an end-user opens Firebug?

Comment: @Jan: I see. I assumed the if condition was to hide it (as an alternative to deleting the line), rather than avoid a null error (as an alternative to commenting it out).

Comment: it's also useful for not letting IE throw an error for console not being defined

Comment: Imho, better than checking every time if console.log is available is better to have something like this:if(typeof(console) == 'undefined') {
    console = {'log': function() {return}}
}
In such case you can write console.log every time you need without checking the presence of it!

Comment: `if (console.log)` (or even `if (console && console.log)`) will still throw an error if console is not available. You should use `window.console` (as `window` is guaranteed to exist) and only check one depth level at one time.

Comment: also can use like this.... `var variable = 12;`  
`console.log("variable value equal to %d", variable)`

Comment: IE drives me nuts, he did not run the whole script (because of console.log in between). But when I opened the console to see what's wrong, everything seemed fine. Reason: console.log now works (until the browser is restarted) … So thanks for the tip with if(window.console && window.console.log ) and *censored* IE!

Comment: The OP does not mention jQuery, and since you explain console.log is "not a jQuery feature," then why clutter the answer by including things it's not?

Comment: @Mac original version of the question asked about jQuery, it since got edited out (not sure why) by other people. So that is why.

Comment: Some tips:

You can use colors to have a better view of:
console.log('%c Sample Text', 'color:green;');

Or add some VAR in the text using:
console.log(\`Sample ${variable}\`, 'color:green;');

Answer (score 227):

Places you can view the console! Just to have them all in one answer.

**Firefox**

http://getfirebug.com/

(you can also now use Firefox's built in developer tools Ctrl+Shift+J (Tools > Web Developer > Error Console), but Firebug is much better; use Firebug)

**Safari and Chrome**

Basically the same.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview

https://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html

**Internet Explorer**

Don't forget you can use compatibility modes to debug IE7 and IE8 in IE9 or IE10

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(v=vs.85).aspx

If you must access the console in IE6 for IE7 use the Firebug Lite bookmarklet

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite/ look for stable bookmarklet

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet

**Opera**

http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/

**iOS**

Works for all iPhones, iPod touch and iPads.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html

Now with iOS 6 you can view the console through Safari in OS X if you plug in your device. Or you can do so with the emulator, simply open a Safari browser window and go to the "Develop" tab. There you will find options to get the Safari inspector to communicate with your device.

**Windows Phone, Android**

Both of these have no console built in and no bookmarklet ability. So we use 
http://jsconsole.com/ type :listen and it will give you a script tag to place in your HTML. From then on you can view your console inside the jsconsole website.

**iOS and Android**

You can also use http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/ to access web inspector tools and the console on any device using their convenient browser plugin.

---

**Older browser problems**

Lastly older versions of IE will crash if you use console.log in your code and not have the developer tools open at the same time. Luckily it's an easy fix.  Use the below code snippet at the top of your code:

```
 if(!window.console){ window.console = {log: function(){} }; }
```

This checks to see if the console is present, and if not it sets it to an object with a blank function called `log`. This way window.console and window.console.log is never truly `undefined.`

Comment: Correct me if wrong, but I think there's no need of Firebug in Firefox to view the console, just click Ctrl+Shift+J (Tools > Web Developer > Error Console)

Comment: @Dane411 this is true, but firebug is better and more commonly used.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Someone have to clean out all the junk, but I think that it at some point gets less interesting to harvest those reps and actually keeping the community clean.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, please comment. downvotes without comments are useless

Comment: there was window.dump before window.console.log. It's better than empty log function

Comment: @OCTAGRAM are you saying you downvoted because I didn't mention `window.dump` in a post about `console.log`?

Comment: This needs some serious editing to bring it up to date. 6 of the links in it are now dead.

Comment: @Quentin feel free

Answer (score 102):

You can view any messages logged to the console if you use a tool such as Firebug to inspect your code. Let's say you do this:

```
console.log('Testing console');
```

When you access the console in Firebug (or whichever tool you decide to use to inspect your code), you will see whatever message you told the function to log. This is particularly useful when you want to see if a function is executing, or if a variable is being passed/assigned properly. It's actually rather valuable for figuring out just what went wrong with your code.

Comment: Don't forget to define it first to avoid errors in IE: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7585409/318765

Answer (score 84):

It will post a log message to the browser's javascript console, e.g. Firebug or Developer Tools (Chrome / Safari) and will show the line and file where it was executed from.

Moreover, when you output a jQuery Object it will include a reference to that element in the DOM, and clicking it will go to that in the Elements/HTML tab.

You can use various methods, but beware that for it to work in Firefox, you must have Firebug open, otherwise the whole page will crash. Whether what you're logging is a variable, array, object or DOM element, it will give you a full breakdown including the prototype for the object as well (always interesting to have a poke around). You can also include *as many* arguments as you want, and they will be replaced by spaces.

```
console.log(  myvar, "Logged!");
console.info( myvar, "Logged!");
console.warn( myvar, "Logged!");
console.debug(myvar, "Logged!");
console.error(myvar, "Logged!");
```

These show up with different logos for each command.

You can also use `console.profile(profileName);` to start profiling a function, script etc. And then end it with `console.profileEnd(profileName);` and it will show up in you Profiles tab in Chrome (don't know with FF).

For a complete reference go to http://getfirebug.com/logging **and I suggest you read it.** (Traces, groups, profiling, object inspection).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why is `console.log("x:", x)` better than `console.log("x:" + x)`? Is it less error prone since a `,` is easier to read than a `+`?

Comment: In my opinion it is slightly easier to read when you're outputting many different things. In this case it should probably be using `+` strictly, but I wanted to show that you can also use commas in the console functions. Also, it avoids issues if both of the variables are integers or arrays.

Comment: `console.log("x:", x)` is significantly better, because when `x` is object or array (or anything but string), it gets displayed correctly, without conversion to string.

Answer (score 35):

There is nothing to do with jQuery and if you want to use it I advice you to do

```
if (window.console) {
    console.log("your message")
}
```

So you don't break your code when it is not available.

As suggested in the comment, you can also execute that in one place and then use `console.log` as normal

```
if (!window.console) { window.console = { log: function(){} }; }
```

Comment: May I recommend instead doing `if(!window.console){ window.console = function(){}; }` instead in one place, then using console.log as normal.

Answer (score 23):

`console.log` has nothing to do with jQuery. It is a common object/method provided by debuggers (including the Chrome debugger and Firebug) that allows a script to log data (or objects in most cases) to the JavaScript console.

Answer (score 19):

`console.log` logs debug information to the console on some browsers (Firefox with Firebug installed, Chrome, IE8, anything with Firebug Lite installed). On Firefox it is a very powerful tool, allowing you to inspect objects or examine the layout or other properties of HTML elements. It isn't related to jQuery, but there are two things that are commonly done when using it with jQuery:

- install the [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) extension for Firebug. This, amongst other advantages, makes the logging of jQuery objects look nicer.
- create a wrapper that is more in line with jQuery's chaining code conventions.

This means usually something like this:

```
$.fn.log = function() {
    if (window.console && console.log) {
        console.log(this);
    }
    return this;
}
```

which you can then invoke like

```
$('foo.bar').find(':baz').log().hide();
```

to easily check inside jQuery chains.

Answer (score 16):

`console.log` has nothing to do with jQuery.

It logs a message to a debugging console, such as Firebug.

Answer (score 16):

A point of confusion sometimes is that to log a text message along with the contents of one of your objects using console.log, you have to pass each one of the two as a different argument. This means that you have to separate them by commas because if you were to use the + operator to concatenate the outputs, this would implicitly call the `.toString()` method of your object. This in most cases is not explicitly overriden and the default implementation inherited by `Object` doesn't provide any useful information.

Example to try in console:

```
>>> var myObj = {foo: 'bar'}
undefined
>>> console.log('myObj is: ', myObj);
myObj is: Object { foo= "bar"}
```

whereas if you tried to concatenate the informative text message along with the object's contents you'd get:

```
>>> console.log('myObj is: ' + myObj);
myObj is: [object Object]
```

So keep in mind that console.log in fact takes as many arguments as you like.

Answer (score 13):

Use `console.log` to add debugging information to your page.

Many people use `alert(hasNinjas)` for this purpose but `console.log(hasNinjas)` is easier to work with. Using an alert pop-ups up a modal dialog box that blocks the user interface.

Edit: I agree with [Baptiste Pernet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541796/baptiste-pernet) and [Jan Hančič](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185527/jan-hancic) that it is a very good idea to check if `window.console` is defined first so that your code doesn't break if there is no console available.

Answer (score 12):

An example - suppose you want to know which line of code you were able to run your program (before it broke!), simply type in

```
console.log("You made it to line 26. But then something went very, very wrong.")
```

Answer (score 11):

You use it to debug JavaScript code with either [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) for Firefox, or JavaScript console in [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) browsers.

```
var variable;

console.log(variable);
```

It will display the contents of the variable, even if it is a array or object.

It is similar to `print_r($var);` for [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP).

Comment: A handy tip... I always include the following in a globally accessible javascript file: `if (!window.console) { window.console = { log : function() {} }; }` .  This allows you to get away with forgetting to remove the occasional debug statement.

Comment: @roufamatic I don't know... adding code, to handle code that doesn't belongs, seems like a pretty terrible solution... especially when find/replace is so easy...

Answer (score 10):

Beware: leaving calls to console in your production code will cause your site to break in Internet Explorer.  Never keep it unwrapped.  See: https://web.archive.org/web/20150908041020/blog.patspam.com/2009/the-curse-of-consolelog

Comment: Its not that console log will break if you are using a Windows machine, but it will break your site if you are using Internet Explorer.

Comment: I think that the blog referenced in the answer no longer exists.

Comment: Original link is dead. I have found a Web Archive copy.

Answer (score 10):

In early days JS debugging was performed through `alert()` function - now it is an obsolete practice.

The `console.log()` is a function that writes a message to log on the debugging console, such as  [Webkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) or Firebug. In a browser you will not see anything on the screen. It logs a message to a debugging console. It is only available in Firefox with  Firebug and in Webkit based browsers (Chrome and Safari). [It does not work well in all IE releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function).

The console object is an extension to the DOM.

The `console.log()` should be used in code only during development and debugging.

It’s considered bad practice that someone leaves `console.log()` in the javascript file on the production server.

Answer (score 5):

If your browser supports debugging, you can use the console.log() method to display JavaScript values.

Activate debugging in your browser with <kbd>F12</kbd>, and select "Console" in the debugger menu.

Console in JavaScript. Try to fix, or "debug," a non-functioning JavaScript program, and practice using the console.log() command. There are shortcuts that is going to help you to access to the JavaScript console, based on the browser that you are using:

Chrome Console Keyboard Shortcuts

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
  Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Firefox Console Keyboard Shortcuts

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
 Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Internet Explorer Console Keyboard Shortcuts

<kbd>F12</kbd> key

Safari Console Keyboard Shortcuts

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

It is used to log (anything you pass it) to the [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) console. The main usage would be to debug your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 4):

`console.log` specifically is a method for developers to write code to inconspicuously inform the developers what the code is doing. It can be used to alert you that there's an issue, but shouldn't take the place of an interactive debugger when it comes time to debug the code. Its asynchronous nature means that the [logged values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395718) don't necessarily represent the value when the method was called.

In short: log errors with `console.log` (if available), then fix the errors using your debugger of choice: [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ), WebKit Developer Tools (built-in to [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH8-SW1) and [Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/)), IE Developer Tools or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

I really feel web programming easy when i start `console.log` for debugging.

```
var i;
```

If i want to check value of `i` runtime..

```
console.log(i);
```

you can check current value of `i` in firebug's console tab. It is specially used for debugging.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the usages mentioned above, `console.log` can also print to the terminal in `node.js`. A server created with express (for eg.) can use `console.log` to write to the output logger file.

Answer (score 3):

This is nothing to deal with the jQuery. The `console.log()` is referencing to the console object's log function, which provides methods for logging information to the browser's console. These methods are intended for debugging purposes only and should not be relied on for presenting information to end users.

Comment: EXACTELY THERS'E NOTHING TO BE DONE WITH JQUERY

Answer (score 2):

In java scripts there is no input and output functions. So to debug the code console.log() method is used.It is a method for logging. It will be printed under console log (development tools).

Its is not present in IE8 and under until you open IE development tool.

Answer (score 1):

*[Quoting MDN Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console_API)*

> `console` — contains many methods that you can call to perform
> rudimentary debugging tasks, generally focused around logging various
> values to the browser's Web Console.
>
> By far the most commonly-used method is `console.log`, which is used
> to log the current value contained inside a specific variable.

#### How to use in Javascript?

```
let myString = 'Hello World';
console.log(myString);
```

Also remember `console` is a part of global `window` object in the web browser. Thus the following is also technically correct but isn't used in practical scenario.

```
let myString = 'Hello World';
window.console.log(myString);
```

Comment:  RIGHT CONSOLE IS GLOBAL PART OF WINDOW

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain in easy way:

**Why Useable:**

The *console.log() method writes a message to the console and display it*.

~very useful for testing purposes.

~Use them under/inside script tags.

**How To See:**

=>Press F12

**Syntax:**

console.log(message you want to display);

~Accepts a parameter and display it.

**Working With Array:**

```js
var myArray = ["Ali", "John", "Shahrukh"];
console.log(myArray);
```

**Working With Objects:**

```js
var myObject = { firstname : "Ali", lastname : "Rana" };
console.log(myObject);
```

**Working With Text:[method 1]:**

```js
console.log("Hello StackOverflow");
```

**Working With Text:[method 2]**

```js
var str = "Hello StackOverflow";
console.log(str);
```

**Working With Numbers:**

```js
var myvar = '2';
console.log(myvar);
```

**Working With Function:**

```js
function myfunction() { return (5 * 19); }
console.log(function());
```

**Display Message With Argument:**

```js
var a = 2;
console.log("The value of a is " + a);
```

Hope, It May Helps.

Answer (score 0):

The console.log() is a function in JavaScript which is used to print any kind of variables defined before in it or to just print any message that needs to be displayed to the user.

EG CODE:

```
function func() { return (5 * 18); }
     console.log(func());
```

IMG:

[image]

OUTPUT:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**console.log()** : This method is well known and most common which can output anything of any type. Pass string, number, object or even html elements as a parameter and it will print same for you.

Ex.

```
console.log('Your print statements here!');
console.log('2nd parameter is type object', {type: 'object'});
console.log('can print with multiple parameters', 100001, {type: 'object'});
```

***Find more about console with examples from here: [console](https://medium.com/@tapaswim/console-871d590d1499)***

Answer (score 0):

**console.log() is for a developer to generally logging output information.**

You also have other console methods as shown below

console.assert()

//Log a message and stack trace to console if the first argument is false.

console.clear()

// Clear the console.

console.count()

// Log the number of times this line has been called with the given label.

console.countReset()

// Resets the value of the counter with the given label.

console.debug()

// Outputs a message to the console with the log level debug.

console.dir()

// Displays an interactive listing of the properties of a specified JavaScript object. This listing lets you use disclosure triangles to examine the contents of child objects.

console.dirxml()

// Displays an XML/HTML Element representation of the specified object if possible or the JavaScript Object view if it is not possible.

console.error()

// Outputs an error message. You may use string substitution and additional arguments with this method.

console.exception()

// Non-Standard
// An alias for error().

console.group()

// Creates a new inline group, indenting all following output by another level. To move back out a level, call groupEnd().

console.groupCollapsed()

// Creates a new inline group, indenting all following output by another level. However, unlike group() this starts with the inline group collapsed requiring the use of a disclosure button to expand it. To move back out a level, call groupEnd().

console.groupEnd()

// Exits the current inline group.

console.info()

// Informative logging of information. You may use string substitution and additional arguments with this method.

console.log()

// For general output of logging information. You may use string substitution and additional arguments with this method.

console.profile()

// Non-Standard
// Starts the browser's built-in profiler (for example, the Firefox performance tool). You can specify an optional name for the profile.

console.profileEnd()

// Non-Standard
// Stops the profiler. You can see the resulting profile in the browser's performance tool (for example, the Firefox performance tool).

console.table()

// Displays tabular data as a table.

console.time()

// Starts a timer with a name specified as an input parameter. Up to 10,000 simultaneous timers can run on a given page.

console.timeEnd()

// Stops the specified timer and logs the elapsed time in milliseconds since it started.

console.timeLog()

// Logs the value of the specified timer to the console.

console.timeStamp()

// Non-Standard
// Adds a marker to the browser's Timeline or Waterfall tool.

console.trace()

// Outputs a stack trace.

console.warn()

Answer (score 0):

It's need to understand that `console` object and its methods are not part of JavaScript.
This is a part of host environment that runs JS code.
Examples of host environments: NodeJS, browsers, Bun.
There is no documentation about `console` in EcmaScript.
But `console` is available in all modern JS runtimes.

Besides, I found that `console` has its own specification:
https://console.spec.whatwg.org