# JavaScript closure loses this reference?

Tags: javascript, closures

Consider the following code:

```
<script>
    var i = 0;
    function test() {
        var _this = this;
        // foo and _this.foo are set to the same number
        var foo = _this.foo = i++;

        function wtf() {
            console.log(_this.foo, foo);
        }

        $("#thediv").click(wtf);
    };
    test();
    test();
    test();
</script>
```

It seems that console.log(_this.foo, foo) should always output equal numbers (i).

But clicking the div outputs 3 lines (for each console.log call):

```
2 0
2 1
2 2
```

It seems that `_this.foo` always refers to last `this.foo`. Why it is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When test() is run, `this` is a reference to `window` for each of your three test() calls, so you are actually updating `window.foo` when you assign to `_this.foo` and referencing `window.foo` in your `console.log`.

Then, when `wtf()` is invoked, the `_this` variables in each of the `wtf()` closures are the same - they all point to `window`

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8cyHm/

I added some additional parameters to console.log to show what is happening

Comment: Why downvoted? He's right.. I didn't explain that `this` is actually `window` (that's accurate but irrelevant), but he explained it well and gave an example!

Answer (score 3):

In your function `wtf`, the value captured in the variable `foo` is a scalar - the actual numeric value. Since it's capturing the scalar value at the moment the function is created, that function is closing over the value 0, 1, 2, etc. That's why it seems to increment.

However, when _this is captured, it's captured as a reference to a single instance which has a *field* named foo. Therefore, with _this.foo, you are referring to a field on the same instance.

So to sum it up, value types like integers are captured by their value, whereas an object is captured by it's reference.

Comment: This is the right answer. Another way to look at it is the foo variable is created each time you call the test method. Whereas the _this.foo is always referring to the same variable. The this.foo is essentially window.foo, so you each time you call the test method the window.foo variable is set to the new value. When you call the wtf method the window.foo value is going to be the last value assigned to it.

Comment: Great explanation... it's a lot easier to understand after coming from a C# background which has explicit value vs. reference types...

Answer (score 1):

Its a tricky one, :)

The first and foremost thing that you have to understand is, you are calling the `test` function without a `new` prefix, which makes the `this` pointer inside the function refer to the `window` object

```
<script>
    var i = 0;
    function test() {
        var _this = this; //** this referes to the window object
        var foo = _this.foo = i++; //** incrementing the global var and assigning that to a local var and a window.foo var

        function wtf() {
            console.log(_this.foo, foo); //** reads window.foo and its local var foo
        }

        $("#thediv").click(wtf); //** creates a new lister every time the test function gets called
    };
    //** calling without the new keyword
    test(); //** creates foo-1, and wft-1 in memory, assigns foo-1=0; window.foo=0
    test(); //** creates foo-2, and wft-2 in memory, assigns foo-2=1; window.foo=1
    test(); //** creates foo-3, and wft-3 in memory, assigns foo-3=2; window.foo=2
</script>
```

(plz read the commented part inside the code)

Now, when you click on the `div`, which practically has 3 functions listening to its click event (3 inline `wtf` functions inside the `test` function)(each call to the `test` function creates a new `wtf` inline function). Each of these inline functions reads its on local var `foo` each of then have values `1,2,3` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is how it works:

The `test` function is invoked three times. Each time a **different** `wtf` function object is created and bound to the DIV as its click handler. This means that after your above code is executed, there will be **three click handlers** bound to the DIV. When you then click on the DIV, those three handlers are invoked in sequence.

This line

```
var _this = this;
```

merely stores the global object into the local variable `_this`. If the function `test` were to be invoked in an strict-mode environment, `this` would be `undefined` and the code would throw an error. However, since it's not strict mode, the `this` value refers to the global object.

Btw, the `i` variable is declared in global code which makes it a global variable (global property).

This line

```
var foo = _this.foo = i++;
```

assigns the current value of `i` both to the local variable `foo` and to `_this.foo`. And since `_this` is a reference to the global object, the property `foo` is a global property (just like `i`).

Now, since we invoked the `test` function three times, there are also three separate `foo` local variables. Each of these variables captures the value of the `i` variable in the moment the `test` function was invoked. So, the values of those three `foo` variables are `0`, `1`, and `2`. Those variables are captured by the three `wtf` functions (respectively) through closure. (The first `wtf` function captures the first `foo` variable, and so on.)

However, unlike the `foo` variables, there is **only one** `foo` global property. So, after each invocation of the `test` function, the `foo` global property is incremented. As a result, after `test` has been invoked three times, the value of `_this.foo` is `2`. (This is *before* the DIV was clicked.)

Now, when the DIV is clicked, the three `wtf` functions will execute. Each of those functions will print the value of `_this.foo` which is `2`. However, each of those `wtf` functions captured a **different** `foo` variable through closure. The values of those three `foo` variables are `0`, `1`, and `2`, respectively.

Answer (score -2):

If you are testing in Chrome you may well be hitting a bug in console.log.
See : [Javascript Funky array mishap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395718/javascript-funky-array-mishap/8396289#8396289)

Try changing to :

```
console.log(_this.foo + ' = ' + foo);
```

Comment: That's not related to the problem.