# How do I use shift inside a loop?

Tags: javascript

When I run this code:

```
var a = ['a','b','c'];
var b = ['a','b','c'];

for(i = 0; i <= a.length-1; i++){
    b.shift();
    console.log(b);
}
```

I expected this output:

```
['b','c']
['c']
[]
```

But I get this output:

```
[]
[]
[]
```

Why?

And how do I get my expected output?

Comment: I do get your desired output.. I guess the console.log isn't a console.log in your current code.

Comment: I'm getting the exact output you expect with the same code

Comment: Your code is working correctly for me. What you've specified as expected output is exactly what i get when i run your code from Firebug console. In Chrome console, i'm getting the same output as what you're getting. So looks like an issue in Chrome?

Comment: Hmm.. Interesting.. Looks like Chrome's console.log caches the output and flushes it out together after the loop! If you do a shift() and log (not in the loop), you'll get the correct output. But if you put it in a loop, it prints out the final value of b in all three cases!

Comment: It's a webkit "issue" with console.log, there are other references to it here on so. Another "fix" is to use tostring() in your log

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [known problem in Chrome](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-bugs/browse_thread/thread/bbba5a605872738d/cfb826c41ee5e8a1?lnk=raot&pli=1). It's because the `console.log` doesn't make a copy of what you want to display, it just stores the reference.

As the log isn't updated immediately, but once your function ends and the browser updates the user interface, the log will show the current state of the `b` variable, not the state when each `console.log` call was made.

To get the desired ouput you would have to make a flash copy of the state of the variable for each `console.log` call:

```
console.log(b.toString());
```

Comment: Maybe worth noting that Firebug's console behaves differently. I guess it creates a copy of whatever is passed and then prints it.

Comment: To retain the array-semblance inside of the console, you can create another array copy by calling `array.slice()`

Comment: Note: The same happens in Opera

Comment: Note: The same happens in Firefox developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

This is a side-effect of the `console.log` statements not being printed as the statements are executed.  Note that if you replace your `console.log` with `alert`, the code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Or change the log paramater to be an expression as per my answer to [Javascript Funky array mishap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395718/javascript-funky-array-mishap/8396289#8396289)

```
console.log ('' + b);
```