# Polling ajax function is exceeding call stack

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, polling

Suppose I have the following polling function:

```
function pollingFunc(taskId){
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/endpoint',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { 'celery_task_id': taskId },
      success: function(response){
        if(response.celery_ready) {
          console.log('CELERY IS READY')
        } else {
          console.log('polling')
          pollingFunc(response.task_id)
        }
      }
    })
  }, 5000);
}
```

When I invoke it, the success callback is never invoked or it might be, but my console.logs never appear. Instead after a while I get

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

So my function is running recursively, but in the way that I would want it to. I would hope at lease the console log before my recursive calls start would print in the console, but it doesn't. I have confirmed that my backend endpoint is operating correctly and is returning json, so I suspect there is something in my javascript code that I am missing. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: I would add an error handler as well and `console.log` whatever comes in there? Have you confirmed in the network panel that you're getting a 200 response?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but you may be running into the issue with console.log mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395718/javascript-funky-array-mishap.

Comment: There is no recursion in your code in the sense of nested function calls. `setTimeout` is asynchronous and so is `$.ajax`. No `pollingFunc` execution has another `pollingFunc` up the call stack. Something else is going on, that is not shown in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good at js, but I had problems with setTimeout.
According to [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

> Display an alert box after 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds):
>
> `setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);`

So I think your code is waiting 5 secondes before calling your server, and then you call it each time *and immediately* when you get the answer.

=> To fix your problem, put the setTimeout **inside** the success function.

```
function pollingFunc(taskId){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/endpoint',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { 'celery_task_id': taskId },
      success: function(response){
        if(response.celery_ready) {
          console.log('CELERY IS READY')
        } else {
          console.log('polling')
          setTimeout(function() {
            pollingFunc(response.task_id);
          }, 5000);
        }
      });
  }
```

By the way, to not reproduce that kind of problem, I would also declare separately that function, as advised by [JQuery documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/beware-anonymous-functions/).

Comment: Yeah I wanted to have my cake and eat too by having a reusable polling function that is defined outside of the success callback so I can reuse it. If there turns out to be no way to do this, I'll go ahead and accept this answer.

Comment: I edited my answer with an adaptation of your code which is still a reusable function, hope it will help!

Comment: "you call it each time and immediately" - call what immediately? He calls `pollingFunc`, which only queues another `setTimeout` and exits.

Comment: @Igor Yes, you're true.