# JSON splitting data with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using json for the first time so this may be a bit of a stupid question.

My PHP code for returning json is as follows:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM user_db WHERE rest_id='$rest_id'";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$row=array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows{'Users'][] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

This returns the following:

```
{"Users":
[{"user_id":"1361453832p3y","name":"","username":"sideshow","password":"sideshow","user_type":"1","rest_id":"1361453832fxL","email":""},
{"user_id":"1361523362ANq","name":"Sharon","username":"Sharon45","password":"Sharon45","user_type":"3","rest_id":"1361453832fxL","email":""},
{"user_id":"1361523653SXp","name":"Heather F","username":"fishface","password":"golliwog","user_type":"3","rest_id":"1361453832fxL","email":""}]}
```

All I am trying to do is to loop out the results and append them to the page.

My current JQuery is:

```
var name="";
        var username="";
        var password="";
        var user_type="";
        var output="";
        var obj=$.parseJSON(html);

        $.each(obj, function(){
            output+="<p><strong>"+this['name']+"</strong></p>";
            output+="<p>Username: "+this['username']+" Password: "+this['password']+"</p>";
            output+="<hr />";
        });


        $('.user_holder').html(output);
```

This just echos out each field three times. I have not found a way to loop through each json field.....

Comment: var obj=$.parseJSON(html); what contains html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var name="";
var username="";
var password="";
var user_type="";
var output="";

$.each($.parseJSON(html).Users, function(){
    output+="<p><strong>"+this['name']+"</strong></p>";
    output+="<p>Username: "+this['username']+" Password: "+this['password']+"</p>";
    output+="<hr />";
});
```

As you see the only difference is in the `$.each` method where we pass the `Users` property instead of the whole object.

Here is the `output`

```
<p><strong></strong></p><p>Username: sideshow Password: sideshow</p><hr /><p><strong>Sharon</strong></p><p>Username: Sharon45 Password: Sharon45</p><hr /><p><strong>Heather F</strong></p><p>Username: fishface Password: golliwog</p><hr />
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
$.each(obj, function(){
```

to this:

```
$.each(obj.Users, function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each JSON object and reference an index containing the data and the reference the key.

for example

```
 obj['Users'][0]['Username']
```

will return the first instance of username.

so you will need to use a nested for loop to loop through the data.

Comment: How do I get a count for the returned data ? This is where I seem to be stuck

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are sooo close to nailing it.  I think you are just not referencing the Users field in obj.

```
$.each(obj.Users, function(){
    output+="<p><strong>"+this['name']+"</strong></p>";
    output+="<p>Username: "+this['username']+" Password: "+this['password']+"</p>";
    output+="<hr />";
});
```

console.log is your friend :)  If you did

> console.log(obj)

you could inspect what obj was, and see it has a Users field, and you'd be laughing :)

To learn about console.log, see this question: [What is console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.each(json,function(i,j){
    $(j).each(function(k,v){    
     console.log(v.user_id);
     console.log(v.username);        
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TvzAX/)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$.each(obj.Users, function(){
        output+="<p><strong>"+this['name']+"</strong></p>";
        output+="<p>Username: "+this['username']+" Password: "+this['password']+"</p>";
        output+="<hr />";
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have tried like this ?

```
         for(var i=0; i < obj.Users.length; i++){
            var username  =obj.Users[i].username;
                //TODO get remaining value of  obj.Users[i];

        }
```