# javascript : matching substring in a string going worng

Tags: javascript

following code works fine

```
var srch_str = "snow"
var str = "snow Showers Late"
alert((new RegExp(srch_str)).test(str))   //true
```

but this one not , i could not get why ?

```
var weather_status = ['rain', 'cloudy', "snow", 'wind', 'thunderstorms' ]
    function getStatus(str){

        for(srch_str in weather_status){


            var bool = (new RegExp(srch_str)).test(str)
            if(bool){
                str = srch_str
                Ti.API.info("if ......")
                break;
            }
            else{
                Ti.API.info(" else ----------")
            }

        }//for

        return str
    }
```

output :   else ------------  (5 times)

when calling `getStatus("snow Showers Late")`

Comment: `for..in` is for objects not arrays.

Comment: @elclanrs Arrays are objects.

Comment: RegEx is clunky, making it worse is a new Regex object per iteration. Tsk3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you loop with `for(srch_str in weather_status)` the `srch_str` is the index of the array, not the element at that index. Change the regex line to:

```
var bool = (new RegExp(weather_status[srch_str])).test(str);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q688j/

(Debugging tip: `console.log( srch_str )` would have pointed out the problem right away.)

Comment: Works for me. (You do have the console open...?)

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log

Comment: i opened console, on running the code, another window opens with message {"error": "Please use POST request"}