# Javascript dialog boxes (alert box) in Eclipse too big to close

Tags: javascript, eclipse, alert

I am working on a JavaScript file and using the alert() method to print some object information. I am testing my ".js" file on Eclipse.
Every now and then this information is to big to fit in the alert box so I see the alert box but am unable to see the OK button (located usually in the end of the alert box). So I end up force quitting Eclipse. The same thing also happens  with some browsers (Google Chrome). Is there any way to prevent force quitting or is this somehow preventable?

I know this question is somewhat general but it happened to me a lot recently and I am wondering if this can be avoided.

Comment: I suggest using [`console.log`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log) for debugging, theres [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox and Chrome already comes with Developer tools. Avoid this whole problem with Eclipse altogether, debug within your browser at runtime.

Comment: Reference for [Console Object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2012/01/03/10168757.aspx). Keep in mind that  there are differences between console object for each Developer Tools. New versions of Firefox doesn't needed the Firebug extension, there's a built-in Web Console. IE and Opera also have a console.

Comment: @sweetamylase I am working with console.log now. I did not know it before.

Comment: @gfcarv Thank you for pointing that Firefox does not need the Firebug extension, because Firebug slows my browser.