# How to show print_r() content in alert message box?

Tags: javascript, php, alert

I know that whenever I write

```
$food = array('fruit'=>'apple', 'veggie'=>'tomato', 'bread'=>'wheat');
$text = print_r($food, true);
echo $text;
```

**Output will be:**

> Array('fruit'=>'apple', 'veggie'=>'tomato', 'bread'=>'wheat')

But when I am trying to display this via alert message box, it does not show anything.

**The code for js alert I wrote as follows:**

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('{$text}') </script>";
```

This does not work. When I assign a different string to $text then it works. Seems like alert() does not like the format of $test string. **If I write in this way:**

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Array('fruit'=>'apple', 'veggie'=>'tomato', 'bread'=>'wheat')') </script>";
```

I get the correct output. So not sure what is wrong there.

Comment: please do a view source and post the script tag your web page contains.

Comment: `alert("{$text}")` perhaps

Comment: Why on earth are'nt you using the console for this? alert() is not a debugging tool.

Comment: @adeneo: please give me an example of how to use it based on my example. Thanks

Comment: `echo 'console.log("' . $text . '")';`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert PHP array into javascript array you must use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a format for data-interchange between programming languages based on the JavaScript. Because JSON is a text format, the result of encoding can be used as a string or as a javascript object.

```
$food = array('fruit'=>'apple', 'veggie'=>'tomato', 'bread'=>'wheat');

// show the array as string representation of javascript object
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('".json_encode($food)."') </script>";

// show the array as javascript object
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert(".json_encode($food).") </script>";

// show the output of print_r function as a string
$text = print_r($food, true);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert(".json_encode($text).") </script>";
```

A few tips for debugging:

- for inspection of JavaScript objects, [console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log) is a very useful
- if you want a cleaner `print_r` output ( on Windows) use:

  ```
  function print_r2($val){
      echo '<pre>'.print_r($val, true).'</pre>';
  }
  ```