# AJAX signup form with PHP failing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

My websites signup for script is below. When a user clicks signup, it sends all the data to another page through AJAX, if it is successful, it is supposed to change the page, however, it seems as soon as I call the function, the page reloads to the homepage with `top.location.href = '/';` instead of waiting for success of the AJAX call.

What am I doing wrong and how could I fix it?

```
<script>
    $("#button").click(function() { 
        username = $('#loginNames').val();
        password = $('#passwords').val();
        email = $('#email').val();
        q = $('#q').val();
        a = $('#a').val();
        name = $('#i7').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "signupprocess.php",
            data: {'username':username, 'password': password, 'email': email, 'q':q, 'a':a, 'name': name},
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                if(response === up) {
                top.location.href = '/';
                } else {
                    $('#response').html(response);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you add a `console.log()` on both `if` and `else` of the success function? what do you get then?

Comment: what is the function of console.log() ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log - you can use alert also, instead of console...

Comment: What is `up` in `if(response === up)`?

Comment: up is supposed to be 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 2 problems with your code:

### 1st Problem

You need a `preventDefault()`, just add it anywhere in your `click()` function

So:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
```

Should become

```
$("#button").click(function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();
```

From the method documentation:

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.  - [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

So in your case, your code doesn't cancel the default button behaviour unless you add a `preventDefault()`

---

### 2nd problem (not an answer though)

You shouldn't use `click` on the button, you should use `submit` on the form, this way you catch the form submit whatever the triggering event was, the user could submit the form by pressing enter, I do it all the time and I bet this is what you do too.

Comment: to the editor, you have to click a button to sumbit the form, plus the form top says <form onsubmit = return false>