# VS 2012: Real support for debugging via Chrome now is supported?

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

Can we now debug websites / services and set break points while using Google Chrome as the browser ? Or is this still only supportable in IE ?

I know before setting breakpoints (F9) and then debugging in IE worked without problems but using chrome was never supported.

I have tried to use google to find the answer to this but I am still unable to confirm it, I can't believe that debugging on services / sites are still not support in VS via another browser apart from IE.

I know the VS 2013 is upcoming, maybe this will address the problem?

**EDIT**

Sorry i should have made it clear, i am talking about client side debugging directly in VS using a NON IE Browser

Comment: I guess it's something that browsers should support not VS don't you think so.

Comment: Do you want to debug server or client-side? If client-side the problem is not Visual Studio but the browser, if server-side you can do it by attaching the debugger.

Comment: question, updated, sorry should have been more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding client and server-side.

**Client-side:**

We don't care if the website is developed in .Net, with Visual Studio, PHP or whatever you want, the browser gives you some tools for debugging websites so the problem is from the browser not Visual Studio. Even if you upgrade to VS 2013 that won't change your problem, Visual Studio has no way to know the state of the JavaScript for a page opened by a client for example.

You may have heard about SignalR used in VS 2013 ([Browser link](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/release-notes-%28release-candidate%29) feature) and that may have confused you, if so SignalR is only for refreshing client-side pages when you edit the view for example, but not for debugging.

**Server-side:**

Add your breakpoint in Visual Studio and then attach the debugger (Tools > Attach to process). In that way you will be able to debug server-side code (e.g. C# code) in Visual Studio. Note that the browser has no way to know the code server-side.

Comment: Yes I am talking about client side debugging but directly in VS.. this is supported via IE.. and webstorm supports it in chrome... So i presume the answer is still no... no NON IE browser for client script debugging directly in VS?

Comment: Yes the answer is no, you debug your JavaScript/CSS in the browser (F12 developer tools) not in Visual Studio No all browsers have the same features, sometimes I use Chrome, sometimes Firefox or IE. You may be interested by `console.log()`, find more details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log)