# Check Box validation is not working using javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

Whenever Delete button is clicked without selecting any Checkbox it gives validation -thats proper
Whwnever checkbox is selected and button is clicked, also it shows the validation. 
Where am i going wrong ?

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '80'>Q- 80. Statute of Liberty is in ?
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '64'>Q- 64. National Animal ?
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '65'>Q- 65. Popular language
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '63'>Q- 63. Largest Ocean ?
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
function Checked(){
    var chk=false;

    if (document.myForm.check1.checked){
        chk=true;
        return chk;
    } else {
        alert("Please select Checkbox");
        return chk;
    } 
}
```

My Function call:

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" formmethod='post' formaction='/~xyz/cgi-bin/Project/CheckDelete.py' value="Delete" onclick="return Checked()">
```

Comment: if you want to use jquery this will be simple forward ?

Comment: I want using JavaScript only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.myForm.check1.checked
```

As @CBroe adviced, this statement didn't worked *because you're having having multiple checkboxes.*

So you need to *iterate*.

```
 var d = document.myForm.check1;
    var arr = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        if (d[i].checked) {
            arr++;
        }
    }
```

Here I have created a variable `arr`, which gets incremented when a checkbox is checked.

At last I will check like

```
if (arr != 0) return true;
    else {
        alert("Please select Checkbox");
        return false;
    }
```

Finally,

```
function Checked() {
    var d = document.myForm.check1;
    var arr = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        if (d[i].checked) {
            arr++;
        }
    }
    if (arr != 0) return true;
    else {
        alert("Please select Checkbox");
        return false;
    }
}
```

check this in [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/RaA9h/1/)

Comment: It's cleaner that way (actually not using a variable would be even better), but how is it supposed to make any difference?

Comment: @Juhana Thanks, I understood the problem.  Now I have edited, please have a look at it.

Comment: what is this console.log ?? i am not getting that

Comment: @user3003685 Not necessary , *FYI:* `console.log` is like printing the output in the console screen (press f12 in browser and go to console).  It will be useful for debugging the JS.  I guess you're new to JS.

Comment: @user3003685 check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log to learn about `console.log`.

Comment: It worked perfectly....And i got it. console.log is just like printing log to a some file

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple input fields with that name, `document.myForm.check1` will be a *NodeList*, and that has no `checked` property.

What you want to do, is *loop* through your checkboxes, and check their status individually. If in that loop you encounter one that is checked, you can leave the loop by returning `true`, otherwise you return `false` after your loop.

Comment: you mean for(var i=0; i<document.myForm.getElementsByName(check1).length; i++)

Comment: `"check1"` in double quotes in this case of course. Or just keep using `document.myForm.check1`, that has a `length` property as well (as long as you have more than one form element with that name, otherwise it won’t be a NodeList but reference that element directly).