# c# - javascript - checkbox checkall() function

Tags: c#, javascript, checkbox, componentart

I've been trying to implement a checkAll() function in order to select/deselect all the checkboxes inside a grid. The grid I have is this one:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chkImprimir" runat="server" enableviewstate="true" onclick="CheckAll()" />
                    <asp:Label ID="SeleccionarLabel" runat="server" meta:resourceKey="SeleccionarLabel"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonDownloadXLS" ToolTip="ImageButtonDownloadXLS" ImageUrl="SiteImages/toolbar/xls.gif" 
                        onmouseover="this.src='SiteImages/toolbar/xls_hover.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='SiteImages/toolbar/xls.gif';" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="ImageButtonDownloadXLS"
                        Style="float: right;" OnClick="ImageButtonDownloadXLS_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddOfertasDetalle" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" meta:resourceKey="btnAddOfertasDetalle"
                        OnClientClick="javascript:AddOfertasDetalle()" Text="Afegir OfertaDetalle" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="Td2" runat="server" class="generalContent">
                    <ComponentArt:Grid ID="GridOfertasDetalle" runat="server" AllowEditing="true" CssClass="Grid"
                        EditOnClickSelectedItem="false" EnableViewState="true" FooterCssClass="GridFooter"
                        Height="350" ImagesBaseUrl="images/" KeyboardEnabled="false" LoadingPanelClientTemplateId="LoadingFeedbackTemplate"
                        LoadingPanelPosition="MiddleCenter" PagerStyle="Numbered" PagerTextCssClass="PagerText"
                        PageSize="15" RunningMode="Client" ShowHeader="False" Width="730"  AllowHorizontalScrolling="True">
                        <Levels>
                            <ComponentArt:GridLevel DataCellCssClass="DataCell" DataKeyField="Id" EditCellCssClass="EditDataCell"       
                                HeadingCellCssClass="HeadingCell" HeadingRowCssClass="HeadingRow" HeadingSelectorCellCssClass="SelectorCell"
                                HeadingTextCssClass="HeadingCellText" SelectedRowCssClass="SelectedRow"
                                RowCssClass="Row" ShowTableHeading="false" SortAscendingImageUrl="asc.gif"
                                SortDescendingImageUrl="desc.gif" SortImageHeight="10" SortImageWidth="10">
                                <Columns>
                                    <ComponentArt:GridColumn AllowEditing="True" Width="15" ColumnType="CheckBox" Align="Center" />

                                    <ComponentArt:GridColumn DataField="Id"/>


                                </Columns>
                            </ComponentArt:GridLevel>
                        </Levels>

        </table>
```

Then I've tried several things in order to implement the checkAll() function:

```
function CheckAll() {
        var grid = GetGrid();
        var check = document.getElementById('<%=chkImprimir.ClientID%>').checked;

        grid.beginUpdate();

        var gridItem;
        var itemIndex = 0;
        while (gridItem = GetGrid().get_table().GetRow(itemIndex)) {
            gridItem.setValue(0, check, false);
            itemIndex++;
        }

        grid.endUpdate();
        grid.Render(); 
    } 

    function GetGrid() 
    {
        return <%= GridOfertasDetalle.ClientObjectId %>;
    }
```

I've also tried:

```
function CheckAll() {
        var grid = GetGrid();
        var check = document.getElementById('<%=chkImprimir.ClientID%>').checked;

        grid.beginUpdate();

        var gridItem;
        var itemIndex = 0;
        while (gridItem = GetGrid().Table.GetRow(itemIndex)) { //<-- change to Table
            gridItem.setValue(0, check); //<-- tried with and without the (x, x, FALSE)
            itemIndex++;
        }

        grid.endUpdate();
        grid.Render(); // <-- tried with and without Render
    } 

    function GetGrid() 
    {
        return <%= GridOfertasDetalle.ClientObjectId %>;
    }
```

Comment: `gridItem = GetGrid2().Table.GetRow(...` mixing javascript with c#, eh?

Comment: Indeed; but this code works fine in 20 others .aspx pages I have; there is something else I'm missing there.

Comment: This might help... http://www.componentart.com/community/forums/p/32823/32823.aspx

Comment: add debugger in CheckAllUsuarios() function and check where it goes wrong. you can check line by line execution and value in running page and compare it with not running page. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/422713/Check-all-checkboxes-in-GridView-using-jQuery

Comment: Extending on Niklas Wingers comment, have you tried running the console and putting some _console.log('...')_ lines in there? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log

Comment: I've tried putting logs verywhere and seeing what was going wrong. Everything seemd fine. The function variables were correct; the index was correct and the gird was being correctly indexed. The problem has to be in something stupid I miss since I can make it work almost everywhere else (but no everywhere!). I'll try to implement the code from the Bhavik link and tell you something.

Comment: How does it get rendered to the page? Use the View Source function in the browser and post the following: 1) The JavaScript code as it is ultimately rendered to the browser, 2) the HTML snippets showing the IDs of each control referenced by the JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a jQuery solution.

A checkbox with ID of `CheckAll` and all checkboxes to be checked or unchecked inside an element with class `wrapper`.

```
$('#CheckAll').click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('.wrapper input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            if (!this.checked) {
                $(this).trigger('click');
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.wrapper input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $(this).trigger('click');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Using the jQuery function `trigger` instead of setting the attribute to `checked` will allow for normal function of any JavaScript events tied to said checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JQuery, for example, if your `GridOfertasDetalle.ClientObjectId` is `offersTable`

```
function checkUncheckAll() {
    var offersTable = $('#offersTable');
    var allCheckBox = $('input[type=checkbox]', offersTable);
    var allCheckBoxChecked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked', offersTable);

    if (allCheckBox.length == allCheckBoxChecked.length) //if all are checked 
    {
       allCheckBox.removeAttr('checked'); //uncheck all
    }
    else allCheckBox.attr('checked', 'checked'); //check all
}
```