# ASP NET function works after second click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

On my Page I've got DropDownList, Date Picker and ASP.NET Button.

When I pick up date and something from list, after click, it should show Google Map with few markers. I'm using **Web Method** to find records in data base filtered by items from list and datepicker.

When I'm trying to get these records from WebMethod I used **AJAX** which returns good JSON, but I've got error: `Too much recursion`.

I tried this JS code:

```
function myFun() {
    DrawMap();
    var SelectedItem = document.getElementById("ctl00_PageContent_DropDownList").value;
    var SelectedDate = document.getElementById("ctl00_PageContent_DatePicker").value;
    PageMethods.MyWebMethod(CarReg, SelectedDate, function (result) {
        parsed = JSON.parse(result);
    });
```

Where `function(result){ parsed = JSON.parse(result);` assigns result to global variable `parsed`.

In my button I've got attribute `OnClientClick` with value `myFun(); return false;` because after postback my map doesn't work. It works, but I have to click twice.

I noticed that when I do `alert(parsed);` after call `MyWebMethod` I got undefined.

Why `parsed` is undefined after assign result?

Comment: can you show your `MyWebMethod`

Comment: `myFun` is executed asynchronously, which means that by the time the browser finishes it's execution, the `AJAX` request (`WebMethod`) didn't got the answer from the server. You should use `alert(parsed)` in the callback function of the `WebMethod`

Comment: @RaraituL Okay, so why my global variable **parsed** doesn't assign result of the **WebMethod**'s callback? _function(result){ parsed = JSON.parse(result);_ should do everything, but it works only by clicking twice. When I make variable **parsed** locally in _myFun_ it won't run.

Comment: @user3692826: It does assign the result to variable `parsed`, but only after the `AJAX` request has ended, which is **after** `myFun` has finished it's execution. It is a simply coincidence that it works the second time, because, by the time you execute it the 2nd time, the 1st `AJAX` request got the answer from the server (and assigned the variable `parsed`). Use [console.log()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log) for debugging and you will see