# meaning of console.log(id); id = id.split(" ");

Tags: jquery

Can someone please explain in simple terms what this does? I looked up but didnt really understand.

First thing is the console.log. I often see this. What does it mean? Then the id.split part is confusing too.

```
console.log(id);
 id = id.split(" ");
```

Comment: You print the id to the console, and then convert the string to an array by splitting it whereever there's a space.

Comment: 2 seconds on Google: [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.log) and [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.log
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp
And, on stackoverflow...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`Console.log` will print the id to the console. And `split` function will split the string into multiple arrays.

For example if `id = "I love stackoverflow";` If you use

`id.split(" ")`

will result in an array with 3 components: **"I"**, **"love"** and **"stackoverflow"**.

Comment: Florin Pop. Thank you for your great explanation. I really did do a google search but there were so many terminologies I didnt understand.

Answer (score -1):

console.log writes the value to the [JavaScript Console](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20console).

`id.split(" ")` splits the string `id` at the space into an array.

```
var id = "This is a string";
var idParts = id.split(" ");

for(var i = 0; i < idParts.length; i++) {
  console.log(idParts[i]);
}
```

The above will output "This", "is", "a", and "string" to the javascript console.