# $.post('link',...) not working

Tags: php, jquery, post

this is my code

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="name"> 
<button id= "det_submit" onclick="submit_det()"> Submit </button>   
<script>
function submit_det() {    
    if(document.getElementById("name").value != "") {   
       $.post(
             'subscribe.php',{email : document.getElementById("name").value},
              function(data){
                  alert(data);
              });
    } else {
         alert("empty");
     }
   } 
</script>
```

the variable email is not sent to subscribe.php page...any help appreciated...Thank you

Comment: does the script get invoked?

Comment: yeah..It is working if the input field is empty

Comment: What jquery version are you using?

Comment: Seems to be working just fine? How are you getting the data on the serverside ?

Comment: Is the `button` descendant of a `<form />` element? Your posted HTML markup suggests not, but...  Anyway, you ***have*** to provide minimalistic sample in question to replicate issue

Comment: I'm new to this can u please tell me how to check whether there is error in console .. @A.Wolff

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log  On windows, press F12, check network tab

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for bugging u all...I have changed the version of Jquery..Now its working..Thank you @ stepozer , and thank you everyone for spending your valuable time..

Comment: But `jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )` was added in jq version 1.0 ?!

Comment: yeah...jst now I have checked it..it's there in 1.0, and to my surprise its working now when a typed the 1.0 version..seems like I have typed a wrong link in script..@ A.Wolff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, your code is good but you didn't include `JQUERY API`, i have added `CDN` link, you can add the local version after downloading it.

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="name">
<button id= "det_submit" onclick="submit_det()"> Submit </button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script>
    function submit_det() {
        if(document.getElementById("name").value != "") {
            $.post(
                'subscribe.php',{email : document.getElementById("name").value},
                function(data){
                    alert(data);
                });
        } else {
            alert("empty");
        }
    }
</script>
```