# jQuery .is() - $(...).is(...).click does not return object, what does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-click-event, typeerror

`.is()` does not return an object:

```
$("div").children().is(".result").click(function () { ... } );
```

I receive the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).is(...).click is not a function

Is there a function that does the same thing as `.is()` but returns an object instead of a boolean?

Comment: `.is` doesn't return a jQuery object, `.not` does.

Comment: Have you read the docs? [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) returns a boolean, [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) filters the collection.

Comment: As a joke, you could use: `$("div").not(":not(.result)")`... More seriously use: `$('div.result')`

Comment: …but actually you're looking for `$("div.result")` or `$("div").filter(".result")`

Comment: I am not looking for $("div.result") - I was just using this simplistic example to demonstrate my question.

Comment: @Chad And so what is your question? Can you demonstrate it with more relevant example?

Comment: [**What is console log**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log)

Comment: I added the `.children()` which is what my actual code is using, making it different than just `$("div.result")`

Comment: And then it would be just `$('div').children('.result')`

Comment: Ah I didn't know `children` had a filter.

Comment: @Chad Or `$('div > .result')` but that's completly unrelevant to your former question **...**

Comment: Updated the question to reflect the evolved issue

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.is` just returns a boolean, so it can't be chained.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: Is there a version of `.is()` that returns an object instead of a boolean?

Answer (score 0):

Because simple `$("div.result")` gives you `is` function. So there is no need for separate `is` function chain.

`is` is simple check returns boolean docs are avaliable on: http://api.jquery.com/is/