# yiitrace and logging in yii

Tags: php, yii

As I am new to yii ,I didnt understand the concept of logging,

can anyone explain what is the `logging` and what is the usage of `logging`

1) what does `CVarDumper` class and its usage

2)`Console.log()` is what.

3) and what does the following statement mean

```
<?php  echo Yii::trace(CVarDumper::dumpAsString('--------Exception 1st registration------ '.$finalamt.'  gggggggggggggg  '.$_SESSION['signpledgecode']),'vardump'); ?>
```

can any one explain breifly .thanks in advance ......waiting for suggestions,

Answer (score 0):

1) [Logging](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html#logging) : You can easily log various types of messages, filter them, and gather them at different targets, such as files, databases, emails.

2) [Console.log()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4539270/2492110) : console.log() is used to log (anything you pass it/print) to the Firebug console. The main usage would be to debug your JavaScript code.

3) [CVarDump](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CVarDumper) : CVarDumper is intended to replace the buggy PHP function var_dump and print_r. (Displays the array or variables).

Comment: var_dump() is about what

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php It displays structured information about one or more expressions (arrays/objects/variable) that includes its type and value.