# whats the difference between console.log and return in javascript

Tags: javascript, return

Whats the difference between console.log and return in JavaScript?
they both seen to print out things in terminal.

```
  isPrime(num){
    if (num % i === 0)) {
     return false ;
   }
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
   return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: `return` doesn't print anything. The function that gets the returned value is probably the one that prints the result!!!

Comment: The console ("terminal") will always display the result of the last expression. For example, `console.log("foo")` prints `foo` to console, then returns `undefined`, which is also printed by the console as the last evaluation. `console.log` will print stuff to console even from webpage's code, where evaluations are not printed.

Answer (score 1):

**Return**

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

**Console.log**

> The Console object provides access to the browser's debugging console (e.g., the Web Console in Firefox)

`console.log` Outputs a message to the Web Console under development tool concel tab.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=console
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log
- [What is console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log)

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` is meant to print output to the console.  However, `return` is meant to send data back to variable when a function is called, like this:

```
var foo = bar();
```

If `bar()` had a `return` statement, the value would be passed to `foo`.