# Javascript guessing game, defining onkeyup variable

Tags: javascript, function, onkeyup

Super new to javascript. I'm trying to make a psychic guessing game. Everything here works except the onkeyup function. When I open the console log and type letters, it tells me that the userGuess variable is undefined. How do I defined the userGuess variable to match the onkeyup function?

Thanks:

```
    //Available choices
var letterChoices = ['a', 'b', 'c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

//score
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;
var guesses = 9;
var guessesLeft = 9;
var guessedLetters = [];
var letterToGuess = null;

//computer randomly chooses a letter

var computerGuess = letterChoices [Math.floor(Math.random()*letterChoices.length)];

//guesses left function

var updateGuessesLeft = function() {
    document.querySelector('#guessLeft').innerHTML = "Guesses Left: " + guessesLeft;
};

//letter to guess function

var updateletterToGuess = function(){
    this.letterToGuess = this.letterChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.letterChoices.length)];
};

var updateGuessesSoFar = function(){
    document.querySelector('#let').innerHTML = "Your guesses so far: " + guessedLetters.join(', ');
};

//reset

var reset = function(){
    totalGuesses = 9;
    guessesLeft = 9;
    guessedLetters = [];

    updateletterToGuess();
    updateGuessesSoFar();
    updateGuessesLeft();

};

updateGuessesLeft();
updateletterToGuess();

//user input key

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    guessesLeft--;
    var userGuess;
    console.log(userGuess)

    guessedLetters.push(userGuess);
    updateGuessesLeft();
    updateGuessesSoFar();

        if (guessesLeft > 0){
            if (userGuess === letterToGuess){
                wins++;
                document.querySelector('#wins').innerHTML = 'Wins: ' + wins;
                alert("How did you know!?!");
                reset();
            }
        } else if (guessesLeft == 0){
            losses++;
            document.querySelector('#losses').innerHTML = 'Losses: ' + losses;
            alert("Sorry, you're not a psychic!");

            reset();
        }
}
```

Comment: You're doing `var userGuess; console.log(userGuess);`. The variable `userGuess` is hence `undefined`. Are you trying to take user input using `console.log`? See [_What is console.log_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4539253/2950032)

Comment: I was doing console.log to test if the user input was registering.

Comment: I'm trying to get userGuess become a string, which displays in guessedLetters. and userGuess should be the onkeyup event.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out which was the key that was pressed? You can access it as [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) in the `onkeyup` callback. If not, please provide a minimal working sample, with the precise problem.

Comment: Here's the working example: https://shawnmukherji.github.io/psychic-game/

The problem is that userGuess is undefined. I don't know why. Ideally, every key stroke should be logged in under guessedLetters. 

ex: a, t, y, m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `userGuess` is `undefined` because it is just declared. There is no assignment operation happening to this variable. I looked at the working sample, modified it in the browser, and it seems to be working as expected. The only change I did was to *assign* `userGuess` to the key pressed, as follows

```
var userGuess = event.key;
```

Here is the output I got by playing around a bit with your code

[image]

Since you have a list of characters that you want to allow, you could add the following code at the beginning, to make sure anything other than the allowed characters are not considered

```
if (letterChoices.indexOf(userGuess) === -1) return;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, appreciate your help!

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept this as the right answer. Cheers!