# [polymer]How should I view the log output?

Tags: node.js, polymer

How should I view the log output? My console does not output the corresponding content, who can help me? Thank you.

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAlVo.png)

[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Matpy.png)

Comment: Check browser console.

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log

Comment: thks ,it ok ;).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special with Polymer - You'll see the result of your statement, `console.info("log test")`, in the console of developer tools. e.g.

- Chrome, https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#console
- FireFox, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console#Browser_Console_logging